# Mapped Google Drive G: showing higher then expected space usage

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, google-drive

When I log into the Google Drive web UI, it shows I have used "101.87 GB of 200 GB", so about **98 GB** free.

However, when I click "This PC" from my laptop - which I have sync'd with Google Drive - it shows for "Google Drive G:" that I have a mere "**6.67 GB** free of 200 GB". So how do I determine which is correct? And what could account for this discrepancy?

It does seem like Google Drive is taking up a huge amount of my 226 GB hard drive. I say that because not only does the Google Drive G: drive say I only have 6.67 free of 200 GB (despite the Google Drive web ui showing I'm only using 101.87), but my 226 GB hard drive really does seem to be unexplainedly almost entirely used up by Google Drive - because I have hardly anything on it except the files (102 GB worth) I have sync'd with Google Drive. I should have more available space than is showing.

What could possibly explain this? How would I even troubleshoot this?

My guess is Google Drive's assessment that I've only used about 102 GB of my 200 GB is correct and my laptop is somehow out of sync with that, but it's unclear to me how to prove and/or resolve this.

I've tried re-installing Google Drive and the mismatch remains. I believe the Google Drive sync software changed at some point a little while back. Could that have duplicated the files on my hard drive? Is there some way to test this theory?

Comment: If some of the files are *duplicates, or different versions* of files, having the same name, when downloading to the PC, some will be overwritten, so there's only one version on the PC. Also, have you cleared out the Google Drive Trash? Trash also takes up space. https://thedaily.case.edu/items-google-drive-trash-saved-60-days/

Comment: What’s more likely is due to the way the drive is mounted what is actually reporting is the amount that exists on your system. I wouldn’t trust the properties of the mounted network drive since it’s only virtual.

Comment: @DrMoishe, I have cleared out the trash and that had no effect.

Comment: @Ramhound, are you saying maybe there are files on my local drive that have not sync'd up to my Google Drive in the cloud? That sounds plausible and would perhaps explain this. But the Google Drive app status shows "Everything is up to date". Is that what you would expect in this scenario?

Comment: I am simply saying the properties of the mounted virtual drive isn’t accurate and likely NOT reporting the allowed free space on your account (how the drive is mounted has no way to determine how much space is allowed on your particular account), it’s not using a Google API to accomplish it.

Comment: OK, that does seem to make sense. Not sure how to go about resolving that, so I'm still stumped. Seems like an issue with the Google Drive client if I follow. When I uninstall Google Drive the G: drive disappears (from windows explorer). Then after I re-install, the size mismatch also re-appears.

Comment: BTW, what does the C: drive usage have to do with this (virtual) G: drive usage? It shouldn't have to do with one another.

Comment: @Yisroel, I mentioned the C: drive because I don't actually have much on it - except for the directories that I'm sync'ing with Google Drive. I have a 226 GB hard drive and I have 102 GB of that sync'd to Google Drive. The rest is mostly empty. It indicates to me that my drive seems to "think"/indicate that it's more full than it really is.

Comment: I doubt this is related. When you uninstall Google Drive the C: drive usage also goes down? (You can use a program like [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) to see what's using space on your C: drive, make sure to run it as Admin.)